# Scaling bitmaps on SurfaceView = no antialiasing?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, surfaceview

I am trying to scale DOWN a high resolution .png bitmap on my SurfaceView canvas like so:

```
Bitmap player = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player);
Paint paint;
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setDither(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
//then in onDraw:
canvas.drawBitmap(player, null, frame, paint);
```

The problem is that the antialiasing works perfectly when I use a View, but it fails to work when I use a SurfaceView, and the quality looks horrible. I've tried everything. Some guy even posted this question 3 years ago on various sites (even here) and there was no resolution. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the original question the guy posted: [Drawing scaled bitmaps on a SurfaceView -- no antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087019/drawing-scaled-bitmaps-on-a-surfaceview-no-antialiasing)

Comment: Guess this doesn't help much but calling setFlags(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) will clear dither and filter bitmap flags set previously. Maybe comparing Canvas objects between View and SurfaceView you draw into gives best results though. Ie. are both HW accelerated etc.

Comment: Yeah apparently SurfaceView can't be HW accelerated so I guess that's the problem. It's a nightmare developing for android - everything I try there's new problems. It's taking me 2+ weeks to develop a game for android which took me 2 days to develop for iOS (with no prior iOS experience).